# Javascript function who is older comparing two objects

Tags: javascript, object

I'm struggling to figure out how write out this function for my class, given these objects and returning the name between the two of who is oldest.

```
({name: "Justin", age: 23}, {name: "Shawn", age: 19}) => returns "Justin"

({name: "Taylor", age: 27}, {name: "Katy", age: 32}) => returns "Katy"

({name: "Miley", age: 24}, {name: "Ariana", age: 24})=> returns null
```

i've been searching it for the last few hours but still coming up empty handed here. If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

Comment: What have you tried already and what output are you getting? please, post the snippets of code that you already wrote.

Comment: Hint: Start with `if (arg1.age > arg2.age)`

Comment: Do you now how to reference an property in an object? Do you know how to compare numbers?

Comment: That's where i'm stuck, in getting this one set up, just trying to get pointed in the correct direction

Comment: using (.name) or (.age) to reference the properties in the object

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that will make an array of each object with `Object.values()`, then compare `array[1]` from both arrays (which will be the position of the age) to see which is bigger, then return `array[0]` from the winning array (since that will be the name position).

Remember to store each array into a variable inside the function.

More than that and I'll code your homework for you.
Search the web for the methods to see how it works if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow isn't really an answer your homework problems for you service, but this is a layout that might point you in a helpful direction.

```js
const group = [
  {name: "Justin", age: 23}, 
  {name: "Shawn", age: 19}
  {name: "Taylor", age: 27}, 
  {name: "Katy", age: 32}
  {name: "Miley", age: 24}, 
  {name: "Ariana", age: 24},
];

const reducer = ({name: minName, age: minAge}, {name: curName, age: curAge}) =>
  /* comparator function */;

const lowest = group.reduce(reducer, group[0]);
```